# why are there not a lot of c++ libraries like in java and javascript

Tags: java, c++, qt

I am just revisiting C++ and I'm already missing all the java libraries like hibernate and JAXB.

So why are there not a lot of open source libraries as there are in java?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask about C++ equivalents for specific libraries. e.g. How would I do something similar to Hibernate?

Comment: There are plenty of open-source 3rd party libraries for C++, most notably Boost (for which the use of the term "third party" has grown more and more meaningless over time.)  But it is true that the standard library is pretty spartan.

Comment: Thank you guys.. So I just have to search for the library when I need one and not reinvent the wheels like I was thinking was going to happen

Comment: Because most C++ developers I know love to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, there are, but maybe not the same. That's maybe because C++ programmers have different needs from Java programmers. And sometimes similar libraries exist, but are named differently. There are plenty of XML parsers for C++ too, but of course they are not called ***Java Architecture*** for XML Binding.

Comment: Frameworks that heavily use introspection might be harder in C++, regardless.

Answer (score 6):

There are lots of C++ open source libraries. Even only boost in enough, to be proud of being C++ programmer.

Answer (score 4):

There is quite a lot of opensource C++ libraries.

Two examples that you mentioned, have a generic names - one is called ORM - object-relational mapping (of which hibernate is a decent Java example), and the other one is just an XML binder.

C++ tools I use for that purpose:

QxORM (http://www.qxorm.com), based on QtSQL, Boost and works marvellous
boost::serialize for XML serialization

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned there are loads of libraries for C++ to do lots of different things but philosophically C (and to a lesser extent c++) are different to Java. The difference is that C (and C++) are a platform enabler. They enable you to program a platform without having to resort to low level assembly but at the same time they give you virtually full access to the said platform. This platform may be some low-level embedded device that does not have a filesystem or even a screen. This will require a very different set of APIs than a normal desktop machine.

It is for this reason that K&R C had NO libraries ISO C has minimal libraries; and it is only relatively recently that projects like Boost are trying to standardize some of the C++ libraries. And even so, some of these "standard" libraries may not be suitable for certain platforms (like kernel development)

Java, however IS the platform. It was written based on the concept of write once run everywhere. This was done by SUN to ensure that Windows x86 did not become the only platform out there. One could write software on Windows x86 and then run it on a SUN SPARC. This required total abstraction from the underlying which in itself requires extensive API support. So even basic J2SE has extensive library support and extensive specifications on how the platform should behave.

So see C and C++ as a platform enabler and Java as a platform.

Answer (score 0):

boost is the equivalent of the java libraries, with lots of different things in it.  I don't like the usability of C++ libraries quite as much sometimes, but then, they are way more efficient and you don't get code bloat like you do in java (just running a program a few lines long means loading that 20Mb rt.jar).

Oddly, apache has the leading XML parser, and it has it in both java and C++

The disadvantage of C++ is that there is no single, consistent feel to the libraries like in Java.  The disadvantage of Java is jar bloat (admittedly fixable with GenJar if you want to do it manually).

I would say that it's Java that is missing the code.  Where is the OpenGL kind of libraries?  They exist (JOGL), but they don't stay current with OpenGL, and since you have to get them yourself, that means you can't deploy without requiring the end user to get them as well.

Comment: Boost is great. However, it is the equivalent of all the mature open-source Java libraries in the same way that Ann Arbor is the equivalent of San Francisco, Boston, London, Tokyo, Paris, Amsterdam, ...